# How to pass a constant to a method as a parameter with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this ( 2 input in the form )

```
 <input type="text" @keypress="onKeypress(e, 'min')">
 <input type="text" @keypress="onKeypress(e, 'max')">
```

In my component :

```
methods: {
 onKeypress(e, type) {
  // find e with the keypress event 
  // find min or max 
 }
}
```

How to retrieve a the value on the keyPress and the constant in the parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `currying`:

```
<input type="text" @keypress="(e) => onKeypress(e, 'min')">
<input type="text" @keypress="(e) => onKeypress(e, 'max')">
```

Because the result of the `event` only broadcasts a single argument, you must `curry` any additional arguments in a function chain.